# Unable to setItem in AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm unable to `setItem` with AsyncStorage. Following is my code. So I'm getting the name in state from a `TextInput` and then want to store it in `AsyncStorage` `onPress` of `TouchableOpacity`. I'm getting error:

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class AsyncStorage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name:''
        }
        //this.asyncSetName = this.asyncSetName.bind(this)   //tried this too.
   };

    asyncSetName(){
        let name = this.state.name
        AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);
    }

    render(){
        <View>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Set Name here'
                onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}
                value={this.state.name}
                autoCorrect={false}
            ></TextInput>

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.asyncSetName.bind(this)}
            >
                <Text>SetName</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity , AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

You will also need to keep the binding of `asyncSetName` function

uncomment this line

```
this.asyncSetName = this.asyncSetName.bind(this)
```

Also as spotted by @Chris you need to change your class name to be different from `AsyncStorage`

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to bind the function in constructor(props) like this `this.asyncSetName = this.asyncSetName.bind(this)` and also call it like this: `onPress={this.asyncSetName.bind(this)}`.
Why do I need to bind it twice?

Comment: you are welcome ... regarding binding you will need to bind it once, i prefer using the one in constructor

Answer (score 2):

1. As @Amir said, you need to import `AsyncStorage` from `react-native`as well as keep the binding as he suggests.
2. You'll probably want to rename your class to something other than `AsyncStorage` too at this point
3. Optionally, you might want to namespace your AsyncStorage key. It's common to put an `@AppName` in front of the key, so your final key would end up being `@AppName${this.state.name}`. But again, this is optional and merely convention.